# How to deal with limits of expressions that have a $(-1)^n$?

Tags: calculus, limits

For example,

I need to find the limit of $$\frac{n^3+(-1)^n n^2}{\sqrt{n^6+1}}$$ as $n$ tends to infinity.

The given answer is 1.

I have trouble getting the answer because I don't know how to take the limit of $(-1)^n n^2$ on account that it $(-1)^n$ has no limit.

So, I thought, the usual algebra of limits does not apply here, so let's try the Squeeze theorem (because that theorem was used to prove the limit of $\frac{\sin(x)}{x}$ and this problem looks similar).

But then, when $n=1$, the expression is $0$. So I can't have $1$ as the lower bound. So what should I do?

Also, in general, how should I approach these kind of problems i.e. where the expression has a term that changes sign.

Comment: Try dividing top and bottom by $n^3$.

Comment: In this case, the numerator is dominated by $n^3$ and the denominator is almost $n^3$. So, I do not think that it is important to worry about the $(-1)^n$.

Comment: In this case, $(-1)^n$ isn't too important because it is dominated by the denominator. However, in general, *use the alternating series test* http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcII/AlternatingSeries.aspx Or the monotone convergence theorem and look where the 2 subsequences go...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case it helps to divide numerator and denominator by $n^3$.
Then you can handle the $(-1)^n$-factor because the product of a bounded sequence and a sequence which converges to $0$ itself converges to $0$.

You get $\frac{n^3+(-1)^nn^2}{\sqrt{n^6+1}} = \frac{1+(-1)^n\frac{1}{n}}{\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{n^6}}} \to \frac{1+0}{\sqrt{1+0}} = 1$